# OPC .Net API C# Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта при записи

Tags: c#, opc

```
Opc.URL url = new Opc.URL("opcda://localhost/VIPA.OPCServer.1");
                Opc.Da.Server server = null;
                OpcCom.Factory fact = new OpcCom.Factory();
                server = new Opc.Da.Server(fact, null);
                server.Subscriptions.Clear();
                server.Connect(url, new Opc.ConnectData(new System.Net.NetworkCredential()));
                Opc.Da.Subscription group;
                Opc.Da.SubscriptionState groupState = new Opc.Da.SubscriptionState();
                groupState.Name = "Group Write";
                groupState.Active = false;
                group = (Opc.Da.Subscription)server.CreateSubscription(groupState);
                Opc.Da.Item[] items = new Opc.Da.Item[37];
                //Цельномолочный цех
                items[0] = new Opc.Da.Item();
                items[0].ItemName = "Vipa/CMC";
                items[1] = new Opc.Da.Item();
                items[1].ItemName = "Vipa/CMCSirieTanki";
                items[2] = new Opc.Da.Item();
                items[2].ItemName = "Vipa/HotCMC";
                items[3] = new Opc.Da.Item();
                items[3].ItemName = "Vipa/CMCCIP";
                items[4] = new Opc.Da.Item();
                items[4].ItemName = "Vipa/CMCCIPObram";
                items[5] = new Opc.Da.Item();
                items[5].ItemName = "Vipa/CMCRozliv";
                items[6] = new Opc.Da.Item();
                items[6].ItemName = "Vipa/CMC3";
                items[7] = new Opc.Da.Item();
                items[7].ItemName = "Vipa/CMCTara";
                //Приемно-аппаратный цех
                items[8] = new Opc.Da.Item();
                items[8].ItemName = "Vipa/PAC";
                items[9] = new Opc.Da.Item();
                items[9].ItemName = "Vipa/PACCIP";
                items[10] = new Opc.Da.Item();
                items[10].ItemName = "Vipa/PACCIPAuto";
                items[11] = new Opc.Da.Item();
                items[11].ItemName = "Vipa/PAC2";
                items[12] = new Opc.Da.Item();
                items[12].ItemName = "Vipa/PACBit";
                //Цех сухого молока
                items[13] = new Opc.Da.Item();
                items[13].ItemName = "Vipa/CSM";
                items[14] = new Opc.Da.Item();
                items[14].ItemName = "Vipa/HotCSM";
                items[15] = new Opc.Da.Item();
                items[15].ItemName = "Vipa/CSM2";
                items[16] = new Opc.Da.Item();
                items[16].ItemName = "Vipa/HotCSM2";
                //АБК и ТВЦ
                items[17] = new Opc.Da.Item();
                items[17].ItemName = "Vipa/ABK";
                items[18] = new Opc.Da.Item();
                items[18].ItemName = "Vipa/HotABK";
                items[19] = new Opc.Da.Item();
                items[19].ItemName = "Vipa/TVC";
                items[20] = new Opc.Da.Item();
                items[20].ItemName = "Vipa/HotTVC";
                //Творожный Цех
                items[21] = new Opc.Da.Item();
                items[21].ItemName = "Vipa/Tvor";
                items[22] = new Opc.Da.Item();
                items[22].ItemName = "Vipa/IceCream";
                items[23] = new Opc.Da.Item();
                items[23].ItemName = "Vipa/Maslo";
                //Цех Стерилизации
                items[24] = new Opc.Da.Item();
                items[24].ItemName = "Vipa/Steril1";
                items[25] = new Opc.Da.Item();
                items[25].ItemName = "Vipa/Steril2";
                items[26] = new Opc.Da.Item();
                items[26].ItemName = "Vipa/HotSterilKont";
                items[27] = new Opc.Da.Item();
                items[27].ItemName = "Vipa/OsmosPodacha";
                items[28] = new Opc.Da.Item();
                items[28].ItemName = "Vipa/OsmosVihod";
                //Котельная
                items[29] = new Opc.Da.Item();
                items[29].ItemName = "Vipa/OsmosPodachaKot";
                items[30] = new Opc.Da.Item();
                items[30].ItemName = "Vipa/OsmosVihodKot";
                //Общий произ счетчик и пар
                items[31] = new Opc.Da.Item();
                items[31].ItemName = "Vipa/Proizv";
                items[32] = new Opc.Da.Item();
                items[32].ItemName = "Vipa/SteamHotWhater";
                //Счетчики Электроэнергии Чиллера
                items[33] = new Opc.Da.Item();
                items[33].ItemName = "Vipa/Chiller1";
                items[34] = new Opc.Da.Item();
                items[34].ItemName = "Vipa/Chiller2";
                items[35] = new Opc.Da.Item();
                items[35].ItemName = "Vipa/Chiller3";
                //Счетчики Электроэнергии ТП1РУ10
                items[36] = new Opc.Da.Item();
                items[36].ItemName = "Vipa/TPLN1";
                //items[37] = new Opc.Da.Item();
                //items[37].ItemName = "VIPA/TP2";
                items = group.AddItems(items);
                    Opc.Da.ItemValue[] writeValues = new Opc.Da.ItemValue[37];
                    writeValues[0] = new Opc.Da.ItemValue();
                    writeValues[1] = new Opc.Da.ItemValue();
                    writeValues[2] = new Opc.Da.ItemValue();
                    writeValues[3] = new Opc.Da.ItemValue();
                    writeValues[4] = new Opc.Da.ItemValue();
                    writeValues[5] = new Opc.Da.ItemValue();
                    writeValues[6] = new Opc.Da.ItemValue();
                    writeValues[7] = new Opc.Da.ItemValue();
                    writeValues[8] = new Opc.Da.ItemValue();
                    writeValues[9] = new Opc.Da.ItemValue();
                    writeValues[10] = new Opc.Da.ItemValue();
                    writeValues[11] = new Opc.Da.ItemValue();
                    writeValues[12] = new Opc.Da.ItemValue();
                    writeValues[13] = new Opc.Da.ItemValue();
                    writeValues[14] = new Opc.Da.ItemValue();
                    writeValues[15] = new Opc.Da.ItemValue();
                    writeValues[16] = new Opc.Da.ItemValue();
                    writeValues[17] = new Opc.Da.ItemValue();
                    writeValues[18] = new Opc.Da.ItemValue();
                    writeValues[19] = new Opc.Da.ItemValue();
                    writeValues[20] = new Opc.Da.ItemValue();
                    writeValues[21] = new Opc.Da.ItemValue();
                    writeValues[22] = new Opc.Da.ItemValue();
                    writeValues[23] = new Opc.Da.ItemValue();
                    writeValues[24] = new Opc.Da.ItemValue();
                    writeValues[25] = new Opc.Da.ItemValue();
                    writeValues[26] = new Opc.Da.ItemValue();
                    writeValues[27] = new Opc.Da.ItemValue();
                    writeValues[28] = new Opc.Da.ItemValue();
                    writeValues[29] = new Opc.Da.ItemValue();
                    writeValues[30] = new Opc.Da.ItemValue();
                    writeValues[31] = new Opc.Da.ItemValue();
                    writeValues[32] = new Opc.Da.ItemValue();
                    writeValues[33] = new Opc.Da.ItemValue();
                    writeValues[34] = new Opc.Da.ItemValue();
                    writeValues[35] = new Opc.Da.ItemValue();
                    writeValues[36] = new Opc.Da.ItemValue();
                    // writeValues[37] = new Opc.Da.ItemValue();
                    //Цельномолочный Цех
                    writeValues[0].ServerHandle = group.Items[0].ServerHandle;
                    writeValues[0].Value = 0;
                    writeValues[1].ServerHandle = group.Items[1].ServerHandle;
                    writeValues[1].Value = 0;
                    writeValues[2].ServerHandle = group.Items[2].ServerHandle;
                    writeValues[2].Value = 0;
                    writeValues[3].ServerHandle = group.Items[3].ServerHandle;
                    writeValues[3].Value = 0;
                    writeValues[4].ServerHandle = group.Items[4].ServerHandle;
                    writeValues[4].Value = 0;
                    writeValues[5].ServerHandle = group.Items[5].ServerHandle;
                    writeValues[5].Value = 0;
                    writeValues[6].ServerHandle = group.Items[6].ServerHandle;
                    writeValues[6].Value = 0;
                    writeValues[7].ServerHandle = group.Items[7].ServerHandle;
                    writeValues[7].Value = 0;
                    //ПАЦ
                    writeValues[8].ServerHandle = group.Items[8].ServerHandle;
                    writeValues[8].Value = 0;
                    writeValues[9].ServerHandle = group.Items[9].ServerHandle;
                    writeValues[9].Value = 0;
                    writeValues[10].ServerHandle = group.Items[10].ServerHandle;
                    writeValues[10].Value = 0;
                    writeValues[11].ServerHandle = group.Items[11].ServerHandle;
                    writeValues[11].Value = 0;
                    writeValues[12].ServerHandle = group.Items[12].ServerHandle;
                    writeValues[12].Value = 0;
                    //ЦСМ
                    writeValues[13].ServerHandle = group.Items[13].ServerHandle;
                    writeValues[13].Value = 0;
                    writeValues[14].ServerHandle = group.Items[14].ServerHandle;
                    writeValues[14].Value = 0;
                    writeValues[15].ServerHandle = group.Items[15].ServerHandle;
                    writeValues[15].Value = 0;
                    writeValues[16].ServerHandle = group.Items[16].ServerHandle;
                    writeValues[16].Value = 0;
                    //АБК и ТВЦ
                    writeValues[17].ServerHandle = group.Items[17].ServerHandle;
                    writeValues[17].Value = 0;
                    writeValues[18].ServerHandle = group.Items[18].ServerHandle;
                    writeValues[18].Value = 0;
                    writeValues[19].ServerHandle = group.Items[19].ServerHandle;
                    writeValues[19].Value = 0;
                    writeValues[20].ServerHandle = group.Items[20].ServerHandle;
                    writeValues[20].Value = 0;
                    //Творожный Цех
                    writeValues[21].ServerHandle = group.Items[21].ServerHandle;
                    writeValues[21].Value = 0;
                    writeValues[22].ServerHandle = group.Items[22].ServerHandle;
                    writeValues[22].Value = 0;
                    writeValues[23].ServerHandle = group.Items[23].ServerHandle;
                    writeValues[23].Value = 0;
                    //Цех Стерилизации
                    writeValues[24].ServerHandle = group.Items[24].ServerHandle;
                    writeValues[24].Value = 0;
                    writeValues[25].ServerHandle = group.Items[25].ServerHandle;
                    writeValues[25].Value = 0;
                    writeValues[26].ServerHandle = group.Items[26].ServerHandle;
                    writeValues[26].Value = 0;
                    writeValues[27].ServerHandle = group.Items[27].ServerHandle;
                    writeValues[27].Value = 0;
                    writeValues[28].ServerHandle = group.Items[28].ServerHandle;
                    writeValues[28].Value = 0;
                    //Котельная
                    writeValues[29].ServerHandle = group.Items[29].ServerHandle;
                    writeValues[29].Value = 0;
                    writeValues[30].ServerHandle = group.Items[30].ServerHandle;
                    writeValues[30].Value = 0;
                    //Общий произ счетчик и пар
                    writeValues[31].ServerHandle = group.Items[31].ServerHandle;
                    writeValues[31].Value = 0;
                    writeValues[32].ServerHandle = group.Items[32].ServerHandle;
                    writeValues[32].Value = 0;
                    //Счетчики Электроэнергии Чиллера
                    writeValues[33].ServerHandle = group.Items[33].ServerHandle;
                    writeValues[33].Value = 0;
                    writeValues[34].ServerHandle = group.Items[34].ServerHandle;
                    writeValues[34].Value = 0;
                    writeValues[35].ServerHandle = group.Items[35].ServerHandle;
                    writeValues[35].Value = 0;
                    //Ввод ТПЛН
                    writeValues[36].ServerHandle = group.Items[36].ServerHandle;
                    writeValues[36].Value = 0;
                    //writeValues[37].ServerHandle = group.Items[37].ServerHandle;
                    //writeValues[37].Value = 0;
                    Opc.IRequest req;
                group.Write(writeValues, 37, new Opc.Da.WriteCompleteEventHandler(WriteCompleteCallback), out req);
```

Вылетает странная ошибка : WriteCompleteCallback Ссылка на объект не указывает экземпляр объекта.

При чем вылетала очень часто на writeValues[37] но я его отключил т.к. он сейчас не используется и датчик выключен, теперь начало на 36 вылетать, но при этом writeValues[36] постоянно имеет какие-то значения.

Запись происходит :

```
       static void WriteCompleteCallback(object clientHandle, Opc.IdentifiedResult[] results)
    {
        foreach (Opc.IdentifiedResult writeResult in results)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(writeResult.ItemName, writeResult.ResultID);
        }
    }
```

Ошибка вылетает с разной периодичностью и только на запись значений, иногда может сутки не появляться иногда через два три часа.
Проблемы только с записью значений в сервер
Что это может быть?

Исключение выскакивает хаотично может 2 дня проработать, может каждый час выскакивать

Текст исключения которое выскакивает

************** Текст исключения **************

System.NullReferenceException: Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта.

в OpcCom.Da.Request.EndRequest(IdentifiedResult[] callbackResults)

в OpcCom.Da.Request.BeginWrite(Int32 cancelID, IdentifiedResult[] results)

в OpcCom.Da.Subscription.Write(ItemValue[] items, Object requestHandle, WriteCompleteEventHandler callback, IRequest& request)

в Opc.Da.Subscription.Write(ItemValue[] items, Object requestHandle, WriteCompleteEventHandler callback, IRequest& request)

в Energocontrol.Main_Form.<>c__DisplayClass132_0.<.ctor>b__78(Object , EventArgs )

в System.Windows.Forms.Timer.OnTick(EventArgs e)

в System.Windows.Forms.Timer.TimerNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)

в System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)

[image: Какое исключение вылетает]

Comment: >Ссылка на объект не указывает экземпляр объекта - достаточно распространенная ошибка, по вашему код я лично ничего сказать не могу. На вашем месте - добавил бы логирование, чтобы понять, когда и кто очищает ссылки.

Comment: можете указать строку на которой происходит указанная ошибка?

Comment: С логированием проблема, т.к. в этом новичек сижу разбираюсь, а в строке writeValues[36].Value = 0; начало происходить, раньше на writeValues[37].Value = 0

Comment: когда происходит исключение на какую указывает?

Comment: `group.Write` тоже код добавьте